# Use error handler to let users try submitting the form again if it didn't work in the first time

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

So, I am building a userform which multiple people will fill. The common database file will be kept at the Sharepoint. The form works perfectly fine only until 2 people arent pressing submit button at the same time.

To counter this issue, I thought of an error handler which will show up when a second user is trying to submit the form at the same time and the message will say someone else is using the form, please try again later.

This is my current Submit code:

```
Sub Submit()
    On Error GoTo eh
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityLow
    If frmForm.txtAE.Value = "" Or frmForm.txtAPL.Value = "" Or frmForm.txtBatches.Value = "" Or frmForm.txtProject.Value = "" Or frmForm.txtQA.Value = "" Or frmForm.txtTeam.Value = "" Or frmForm.cmbDS.Value = "" Or frmForm.cmbPriority.Value = "" Or frmForm.cmbRelease.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox ("Complete All fields marked with (*) to proceed")
    Else
        Dim strFileName As String
        Dim strFileExists As String
        'Call Downloadtest
        strFileName = ""
        strFileExists = Dir(strFileName)

        If strFileName <> "" Then
            MsgBox ("Another user is currently submitting a booking. Please wait for a minute, and then try again.")
        Else

            Dim nwb As Workbook
            Set nwb = Workbooks.Open("sharepoint link")

            nwb.Sheets("Sheet1").Unprotect Password:="password"
            Dim emptyRow As Long
            emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(nwb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")) + 1

            Dim arDate As Variant
            arDate = Split(frmForm.dtPlanned.Value, "/")
            With nwb.Sheets("Sheet1")

                .Cells(emptyRow, 1) = emptyRow - 1
                .Cells(emptyRow, 2) = Date
                .Cells(emptyRow, 3) = frmForm.txtProject.Value
                .Cells(emptyRow, 4) = frmForm.txtTeam.Value
                .Cells(emptyRow, 5) = frmForm.txtAPL.Value
                .Cells(emptyRow, 6) = frmForm.txtQA.Value
                .Cells(emptyRow, 7) = frmForm.txtAE.Value
                .Cells(emptyRow, 8) = frmForm.cmbRelease.Value
                .Cells(emptyRow, 9) = frmForm.cmbDS.Value
                .Cells(emptyRow, 10) = frmForm.txtBatches.Value
                .Cells(emptyRow, 11) = frmForm.dtReview.Value
                .Cells(emptyRow, 12) = frmForm.dtSubmission.Value
                .Cells(emptyRow, 13) = frmForm.dtRelease.Value
                If frmForm.dtPlanned.Value = "" Then .Cells(emptyRow, 14) = "" Else .Cells(emptyRow, 14) = DateSerial(arDate(2), arDate(1), arDate(0))
                .Cells(emptyRow, 15) = frmForm.cmbPriority.Value
                .Cells(emptyRow, 16) = "Pending"
                .Cells(emptyRow, 17) = frmForm.txtRemarks.Value
                .Cells(emptyRow, 18) = Application.UserName

            End With
            nwb.Sheets("Sheet1").Protect Password:="password"
            'nwb.SaveAs ("sharepoint link")


            nwb.SaveAs Filename:="sharepoint link"
            nwb.Close
            'Kill ("C:\Users\username\Downloads\Planning Sheet\KF 6.0_checkout.xlsm")
            MsgBox ("Your Entry has been recorded.")
        End If
    End If
    Unload frmForm
eh:
    MsgBox("Someone else using the file")
End Sub
```

Please ignore the strFilename, strFileexists, I have to clean up that part.

The problem with this is that the form closes, after we click ok on the error.
Any way that we can add a Try again button on the error MsgBox, that users can press so that they can try submitting the form again after few seconds? And also it should prevent closing the userform, as I dont want them to fill the whole thing again if an error is happening.

Please help, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try calling msgbox with `vbAbortRetryCancel` or `vbOKCancel` argument, [enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/msgbox-function) and restructure the sub in a way like:

```
Sub Submit()
     On Error ...
     iStat = vbRetry
     Do While iStat = vbRetry
        ...
         Unload frmForm
         iStat = vbOK 
     eh:
         iStat = MsgBox ("Someone...
     Loop
```